# Using a variable to select an array

Tags: android

I am working on an android app project. I have an array which holds 55 words.  Each word within this array has another array of words which it will use if it is selected. My problem is that I do not know how to access the second array using a variable.

Assuming I put the arrays within the java file and want to access the random array it might be something like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < variable_name.length; i++) {
        arrayList.add(variable_name[i]);    
    }
```

this does not work.

If I put the array into an XML file I would try to access it something like this:

String[] some_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.variable_name);

this does not work.

While irrelevant to the discussion in Actionscript it would be done something like this:

```
      for (var a:int = 0; a < this[variable_name+"Array"].length; a++){
           tempWordList[a] = this[variable_name+"Array"][a];
      }
```

One thing I should add is that the number of elements in the arrays accessed by a variable are not all the same.  e.g. some may have four while another may have six or seven.

Thanks to the input below I was able to come up with a workable solution.  I am new to programing so this my not be the most efficient solution but it does work.

```
    String[] Words = { "zero", "one", "two" };
    String[][] otherWords = { { "green", "blue" }, { "orange", "red" }, { "yellow", "purple" } };

    for (int i = 0; i < Words.length; i++) {
        if (Words[i] == targetWord) {
         arrayLocation = i;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < otherWords[arrayLocation].length; i++) {
        String wordsToAdd = otherWords[arrayLocation][i];
        newWordList.add(wordsToAdd);
    }
```

If the string variable targetWord is equal to "one" the ArrayList newWordList will be equal to "orange" and "red"...

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't allow non-integer indexes for arrays. You have two options. Manager two different arrays like:

```
String[] words = { "zero", "one", "two" };
String[][] otherWords = { { "green", "blue" }, { "orange", "red" }, { "yellow", "purple" } };
```

In a case like this, the index into the array 'words' is used to also index into the array 'otherWords' creating the association.

The other, simpler option is to use a `Map<String, List<String>>` to store your values. In this case, you could simply call map.get("zero") and it would create a List containing the values "green" and "blue". You'd have to write code to load the map with your values so, in the end, you'd probably end up using a combination of the two options.

Comment: Nick ... thanks so much.  I am sure that I will be able to work it out with this info. Michael

Comment: Nick ... would you be able to put a variable in place of "zero" in your example: map.get("zero")?

Comment: Here is my code that works ... I am rather new to programing so I can not say that this is the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

use like this..

```
 mainArray.get(0).get(0).toString();
```

for geting value at index 0 from child array

and this for index 1 from child array

```
 mainArray.get(0).get(1).toString();
```